# Not enough locked memory (rdma_setup_startup_ring: cannot create cq)

Tags: memory, mpi, slurm, infiniband, mvapich2

I have an issue with the quantity of available memory in page locked on CentOS 7.
After allocating nodes with **slurm**, when I launch a job with MPI (mvapich), I encounter the following error:

```
Fatal error in MPI_Init:
Other MPI error, error stack:
MPIR_Init_thread(514).......:
MPID_Init(359)..............: channel initialization failed
MPIDI_CH3_Init(401).........:
MPIDI_CH3I_RDMA_init(221)...:
rdma_setup_startup_ring(410): cannot create cq
```

It seems to be due to a lack of **locked memory**. However, it seems to be set to unlimited since `ulimit -a` returns:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 254957
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 4096
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

When launching `mpirun` with sudo, it is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem came from slurm which did not retrieve the proper value for **max locked memory**. `salloc -N ulimit -l`returned *64* instead of *unlimited*.

The solution is to add the follwing line in **/etc/init.d/slurm**

```
ulimit -l unlimited
```

Then stop and start again slurm:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/slurm stop
sudo /etc/init.d/slurm start
```